# Insert a row for every row in a UDT

Tags: sql-server

Currently have this query:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateTaskInstances]
    @TaskId INT,
    @CreatedByUserId INT,
    @DueDates dbo.DateList READONLY
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO dbo.taskinstance (TaskId, CreatedById, DueDate, RowGuid, CreatedDate) 
    VALUES (@TaskId, @CreatedByUserId, 
            (SELECT CAST(d.item as date) FROM @DueDates d), 
            NEWID(), GETUTCDATE())
END
```

Obviously, this fails because when I pass more than one `DateTime`.

Am I forced to use a for loop here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use that table-valued parameter like table - proper set-based approach, no messy while or for loop needed:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateTaskInstances]
    @TaskId INT,
    @CreatedByUserId INT,
    @DueDates dbo.DateList READONLY
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO dbo.taskinstance (TaskId, CreatedById, DueDate, RowGuid, CreatedDate) 
        SELECT
            @TaskId, @CreatedByUserId, CAST(d.item AS DATE), NEWID(), GETUTCDATE()
        FROM
            @DueDates d
END
```